# Percentage-based fast forward button in GWT SimplePager

Tags: gwt, simplepager

I have a working CellTable with SimplePager attached, and have enabled fast forward button due to large number of rows.

The number of rows can vary quite a bit, and it makes more sense to advance forward proportional to total table size - e.g. 10% on each click instead of 100 records.

- Is there any way to directly set a %age based fast forward button?
- Can we set the fast forward increment at any time after the pager initialization; so that it could be varied based on record count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it manually. If you fetch all the data at once, you will know the total number of records. If you don't make a query to get the total number of records. `Override` click method of fast forward button. Based on the total number of records, and the given percentage to skip, calculate the number of records to be fetched and make a query or show it if you already have the data.

**EDIT :** Fast forward button is a private member and there is no getter and setter for it. There are 2 options for this. Create your own pager class or copy the pager class and place it in a pacakage "com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client" in your project. And make the fastforward button protected or public. This will override the default class.

Comment: The fast forward button itself is not publicly accessible though, how do I override the click method?

Comment: I know. There are 2 options for this. Create your own pager class or copy the pager class and place it in a pacakage "com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client" in your project. And make the fastforward button protected or public. This will override the default class.

Comment: So it can't be done with SimplePager then, if I need to write my own pager class? If you mention that in the answer I'll accept that, thanks!